# DateTime objects from MongoDB have unreadable characters in Object Definition

Tags: mongodb, utf-8, character-encoding

Whenever I fetch data from a MongoDB collection, and one of the fields has a DateTime object, I get this:

```
object(DateTime�����w   )[359]
  public 'date' => string '2012-12-12 00:00:00' (length=19)
  public 'timezone_type' => int 3
  public 'timezone' => string 'America/Caracas' (length=15)
```

I get that when outputting with `var_dump` with UTF-8 charset in the browser, when using print_r, xdebug_var_dump, accessing public methods...

I get this error if I try to output the data of one of those public properties:

> Invalid UTF-8 sequence in argument in (file>)

I am using MongoDB 2.4.3.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT 1:** I thought this was a Symfony-related problem, but I am using Mongo Shell and when I insert a new entry, I have the same problem, so the issue's not coming from Symfony, then it's irrelevant, unless it has to do with the fact that the DB schema was created by Symfony.

Comment: at the shell, how are you inserting new entry?

Comment: `db.collection.insert({new Date('12 Dec, 2012')})`

Comment: that's not legal json.  Do you mean {keyname:new Date(etc)}?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The real issue was a defective installation of the Mongo extension for PHP 5.4. I ended up using [Liip.ch's amazing PHP package for OS X](http://php-osx.liip.ch/), replacing MAMP for me.